# Datagrid displays data in wrong rows

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I am making an program using C# and EntityFrame work with the visual studio 2015. This is a WPF project.

The problem is, when I load data from a database, the datagridview shows the data in wrong rows.   `2016//4/9, Rent, 10000` must be in a same row. But the columns are correct. Please see the picture:

[image]

I am loading the data as follows:

```
using (var context = new MyDataEntities())
        {
            IList<MyTable> dataList = context.MyTable.ToList<MyTable>();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataList;
        }
```

Why are the data shown in wrong rows? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your definition on the xaml of the datagrid but it could be that. It would help if you attach your design on this.

Without alteration 
here's my testing

```
public class RowObj
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }



 void Populate()
    {
        List<RowObj> model = new List<RowObj>();
        model.Add(new RowObj {  Index=1, Data="Apple"});
        model.Add(new RowObj { Index = 2, Data = "Cherry" });
        DG.ItemsSource = model;
        DG.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

[Output grid with 2 rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOUmD.png)

Hope this helps :)